# Recursive MultiThreading with JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, mergesort, repaint

I've looked around, but haven't found anything specific enough to answer my question.
The basic gist is, I've been trying to implement visual sorting algorithms using java's JFrame. Due to having issues with repainting not working in functions/loops, I turned to google and turned to Threading.
My current issue is, implementing recursive algorithms is a major pain, since the threads interfere with each other.
With my professor, I managed to get a solution using .join(), but now I have issues repainting. The sort finishes before any repainting occurs. The general consensus is that there are too many repaint() calls happening and is messing it up.
Can anyone help me with this? I'm fine changing my program so I don't use threading, but I'd like to keep the sort intact.

The sort (MergeSort):

```
     public void MergeSort(Point array[], int start, int end) {
            if (start == end) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                int mid = (end + start) / 2;



            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    MergeSort(array, start, mid);
                    repaint();
                }
            };

            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                        MergeSort(array, mid + 1, end);
                        repaint();
                }
            };

            t1.start();
            t2.start();

            try {
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            int temp[] = new int[array.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = 0;
            }

            int i = 0;

            int x = start;
            int y = mid + 1;

            while (x <= mid && y <= end) {
                if (array[x].y <= array[y].y) {
                    temp[i] = array[x].y;
                    x++;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    temp[i] = array[y].y;
                    y++;
                    i++;
                }
            }

            while (x <= mid) {
                temp[i] = array[x].y;
                x++;
                i++;
            }

            while (y <= end) {
                temp[i] = array[y].y;
                y++;
                i++;
            }

            i = start;
            for(int k = 0; k < end - start + 1; k++) {
                array[i].y = temp[k];
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                repaint();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's called through a JButton:

```
JButton merge = new JButton("Merge");
    merge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (ThreadFinished) {
                populatePoints(array);
                MergeSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    add(merge);
```

Comment: Swing is not thread safe.  What are you doing to synchronize with the Event Dispatch Thread?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: So you turned to *threading* because you had issues with repainting, and now you have issues with repainting.

Comment: Hey follow this link http://www.users.miamioh.edu/karroje/SortingAnimatorThreaded.java  and you can understand where you lacking.